# DLLs missing, application gets 0xc00007b error code

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, dll

On running my `VC++` application doesn't run and stops with `0xc00007b` error code, which is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. I understand that this means I have problems with some x86 - x64 architecture compatibility issues on `DLL`s.

I have checked with `Dependency Walker` and I get the following:

[image]

There is no `64` indicator on any dependency. On double-click on any of the 3 not found files it says it's looking for them in the app folder, although I've copied them there, as well as having *all of them* in `C:\Windows\System32`.

I already have `Visual C++ Redistributables` installed for:

- 2005 - x86 & x64
- 2008 - x86 & x64
- 2010 - x86 & x64

I've run `sfc /scannow` but everything is fine.

The application is `32bit` and it was originally written in `VS2006`, `XP`.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: **Just because you have A version of VC++ installed does not mean you have the version you require**  There is no such thing as **VS2006**

Comment: inside depends.exe, run F7 to stat the tracing: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/06/25/analyze-application-failures-the-easier-way-with-dependency-walker.aspx